# Best way to loop/change some objects in object_list

Tags: python, django

Let say I have this code:

```
# Get 30 threads
threads = Thread.objects.all()[:30]
threads_id = [o.pk for o in threads]
# Extra info about threads that the user have visited
visited_threads = VisitedThread.objects.filter(pk__in=threads_id, user=request.user)

# I want to loop the visited_threads and add info to thread in threads with new info
for visited_thread in visited_threads:
    # Here I want to add things to thread (visited_thread.thread), something like:
    # thread.has_unread_post = thread.post_count > visited_thread.post_count
```

How can I add information to a thread in the threads list, like something in the code example? I don't want to update the database, just manipulate the data before showing it for the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example code you showed is fine, at least in general terms. Once you start iterating over the queryset, Django will create the in memory model instances, and you can add attributes to the in memory versions just like any other Python object.

To be able to edit the threads from your first qs based on the second:

```
threads = Thread.objects.all()[:30]
threads_by_pk = dict((t.pk, t) for t in threads)
# Extra info about threads that the user have visited
visited_threads = VisitedThread.objects.filter(pk__in=threads_by_pk.keys(), user=request.user)

# I want to loop the visited_threads and add info to thread in threads with new info
for visited_thread in visited_threads:
    thread = threads_by_pk[visited_thread.pk]
    thread.has_unread_post = thread.post_count > visited_thread.post_count
```

Comment: Yeah, but how do I add attribute to thread in threads? Let say I have visited_thread with visited_thread.thread.id = 12. How do I add attributes to thread.id = 12 in threads?

Comment: I would build a dictionary of PKs to thread instances from the threads queryset, then you can look up the in memory thread instances in your loop to add the attribute.

Comment: Added an example. It seems slightly suspect that your two thread models seem to share pks, but that's how the question has it.

Comment: Thank you for the example! No, they don't share pks, visited_thread have a foreignkey to thread pk.